# Bootstrap 4 Navbar with container, dropdown alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to limit the contents of the main navbar with a container, I saw it done in a video and I also read in a tutorial that can be done, but is it so? In both cases they did not use dropdowns. The content is correctly aligned to the right and left, but with desktop resolutions larger than the container the dropdown that I have all the way to the right, appears aligned to the page, not to the container.

The dropdown uses a class `dropdown-menu-right`, which sets`left: auto` and `right: 0`, it makes sense that it is aligned to the page, obviously if I remove it it is completely aligned to the left of the page, there is a way with bootstrap classes, without strange hacks, to keep it aligned to the container?

I'm using svelte with sveltestrap, the generated html seems to me like a normal navbar, but I might have missed something, I've been banging my head for a while.

[svelte repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/1781ed81632d48cea5cc1ee0858c8f2b?version=3.18.2)

Comment: Try to set postilion `relative` on `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class position-relative to container. Menu will align according to container.

```
<div class="container position-relative"></div>
```

Comment: Actually I was missing `nav-item dropdown` in the class of the `li` wrapper, but the question was not clear about it, I'll keep as correct